# Полностью скрыть блочный элемент при переполнении

Tags: html, css

Я пытаюсь полностью скрыть дочерние div при переполнении родителя по высоте.
HTML:

```css
    * { margin: 0; }
    .chat {
      position: relative;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: #ff99ff;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .message {
      position: relarive;
      background-color: #99ff99;
      margin: 5px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="chat">
       <div class="message">
         <p>Message 1: String 1</p>
         <p>Message 1: String 2</p>
       </div>
       <div class="message">
         <p>Message 2: String 1</p>
         <p>Message 2: String 2</p>
         <p>Message 2: String 3</p>
         <p>Message 2: String 4</p>
       </div>
       <div class="message">
         <p>Message 3: String 1</p>
         <p>Message 3: String 2</p>
         <p>Message 3: String 3</p>
       </div>
       <div class="message">
         <p>Message 4: String 1</p>
         <p>Message 4: String 2</p>
         <p>Message 4: String 3</p>
       </div>
       <div class="message">
         <p>Message 5: String 1</p>
         <p>Message 5: String 2</p>
         <p>Message 5: String 3</p>
         <p>Message 5: String 4</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34guhp7z/

В данном примере — у родителя установлено свойство `overflow-y: hidden`, но оно скрывает только ту часть div, которая не влезает в родителя. А как сделать, чтобы дочерний div скрывался полностью? В данном примере `Message 5` должен исчезнуть полностью.

Comment: Напишите скрипт. Через стили это невыполнимая задача

Comment: Соглашусь, нужно писать скрипт. Смотреть, для какого дочернего контейнера не хватает места и прятать его.

Comment: Создайте класс песевдо last child и примените к нему visible hiden или display none

Comment: @Andrey и как вы собираетесь применять этот класс по условию? Ведь это основная задача для вопрошающего

Comment: @Andrey и почему только `:last-child`? Ведь не помещаться в контейнер может не только _один_ последний элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целях демонстрации в примере ниже используется `overflow-y: scroll;`.
Скрываются все элементы, лежащие за пределами первого экрана внутри блока.

```js
$('#hide').on('click', function() {
  var chat = $("#chat");
  $('.message').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var visibleHeight = chat.height() + chat.offset()['top'] - that.offset()['top'];
    var trueHeight = that.height();

    if (visibleHeight < trueHeight) {
      that.hide();
    }
  });
});

$('#show').on('click', function() {
  $(".message[style]").show();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
#chat {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 187px;
  background-color: #ff99ff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.message {
  position: relarive;
  background-color: #99ff99;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Скрыть обрезанные блоки</button>
<button id="show">Показать обрезанные блоки</button>
<div id="chat">
  <div class="message c1">
    <p>Message 1: String 1</p>
    <p>Message 1: String 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message c2">
    <p>Message 2: String 3</p>
    <p>Message 2: String 4</p>
    <p>Message 2: String 5</p>
    <p>Message 2: String 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message c3">
    <p>Message 3: String 7</p>
    <p>Message 3: String 8</p>
    <p>Message 3: String 9</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message c4">
    <p>Message 4: String 10</p>
    <p>Message 4: String 11</p>
    <p>Message 4: String 12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message c5">
    <p>Message 5: String 13</p>
    <p>Message 5: String 14</p>
    <p>Message 5: String 15</p>
    <p>Message 5: String 16</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Основано на ответе к вопросу "[Get height of visible portion of div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12868402/2486051)"

Comment: Эх. Не успел :)

Comment: Что-то ваш вариант многовато скрывает. Попробуйте высоту контенера 187px

Comment: @tutankhamun, увеличил, функционирует так же.

Comment: Спасибо! Я хотел убедиться что средствами чистого CSS этого сделать точно нельзя.

Comment: @VenZell У меня если раскрыть результат на всю страницу, видно однипиксельную линию от `Message 4`, но скрывается и `Message 3`, который отображается полностью. Firefox 47 Linux.